# How to simplify multiple condition in an if clause?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have written a code in `Django` like:

```
phone = request.data.get("phone")
password = request.data.get("password")
age = request.data.get("age")
name = request.data.get("name")

if not phone or not password or not age or not name: #multiple not checks
    return Response({"status": False})
```

It takes multiple `not` checks, is here any way to write this in simpler way?

Comment: You can use De Morgan's law and turn it into `not (phone and password and age and name)` which may or may not feel simpler.

Comment: Use `if not any([not phone, not password, not age, not name]):`

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ: If you want to go that route it would be easier using `all` giving `not all([phone, password, age, name])` which is essentially the same as I suggested above.

Comment: @JohanL Yeah , you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **`request.data`** seems an input payload/query parameter. So, I assume that all the data in the **`request.data`** is mandatory.
In this situation you can use the Python's [**`all()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#all) function as

```
if not all([True if v else False for k, v in request.data.items()]):
    return Response({"status": False})
```

This would be very handy if you have large number of fields such as `phone`,`password` etc
Suppose if you have specific fields such as `myfields = ['username','password','name','age']` then use the `all()` function as

```
myfields = ['username', 'password', 'name', 'age']
if not all([True if request.data.get(k) else False for k in myfields]):
    return Response({"status": False})
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't allow anything to be optional or empty there so you can just do:

```
if not (phone and password and age and name):
    return Response({"status": False})
```

If any of the variables inside the brackets is empty/null/false, the whole condition will be false.